# How to generate file name based on values in a data.frame?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file full of data on heights at age 18 varying by year. (data.csv) (You can access it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XkkDgviuiM3rql6ncyT2qIJjMSdmMtba).)

What I want to do is separate all the data into different files with the name of the country.

```
countryList <- unique(data[,1])

for (countries in countryList) {
  print(countries)
  print(class(countries))
  output <- data %>%
    select(`Country`, `Sex`, `Year of birth`, `Mean height (cm)`) %>%
    arrange(`Country`)

  write.table(output, paste("~/Desktop/data/", countries, ".csv", sep=""), col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
}
```

Rather than get a bunch of files each with the name of the country, this is what it outputs:

```
 [1] "Afghanistan"                      "Albania"                         
  [3] "Algeria"                          "American Samoa"                  
  [5] "Andorra"                          "Angola"                          
  [7] "Antigua and Barbuda"              "Argentina"                       
  [9] "Armenia"                          "Australia"                       
 [11] "Austria"                          "Azerbaijan"                      
 [13] "Bahamas"                          "Bahrain"                         
 [15] "Bangladesh"                       "Barbados"                        
 [17] "Belarus"                          "Belgium"                         
 [19] "Belize"                           "Benin"                           
 [21] "Bermuda"                          "Bhutan"                          
 [23] "Bolivia"                          "Bosnia and Herzegovina"          
 [25] "Botswana"                         "Brazil"                          
 [27] "Brunei Darussalam"                "Bulgaria"                        
 [29] "Burkina Faso"                     "Burundi"                         
 [31] "Cabo Verde"                       "Cambodia"                        
 [33] "Cameroon"                         "Canada"                          
 [35] "Central African Republic"         "Chad"                            
 [37] "Chile"                            "China"                           
 [39] "China (Hong Kong SAR)"            "Colombia"                        
 [41] "Comoros"                          "Congo"                           
 [43] "Cook Islands"                     "Costa Rica"                      
 [45] "Cote d'Ivoire"                    "Croatia"                         
 [47] "Cuba"                             "Cyprus"                          
 [49] "Czech Republic"                   "Denmark"                         
 [51] "Djibouti"                         "Dominica"                        
 [53] "Dominican Republic"               "DR Congo"                        
 [55] "Ecuador"                          "Egypt"                           
 [57] "El Salvador"                      "Equatorial Guinea"               
 [59] "Eritrea"                          "Estonia"                         
 [61] "Ethiopia"                         "Fiji"                            
 [63] "Finland"                          "France"                          
 [65] "French Polynesia"                 "Gabon"                           
 [67] "Gambia"                           "Georgia"                         
 [69] "Germany"                          "Ghana"                           
 [71] "Greece"                           "Greenland"                       
 [73] "Grenada"                          "Guatemala"                       
 [75] "Guinea"                           "Guinea Bissau"                   
 [77] "Guyana"                           "Haiti"                           
 [79] "Honduras"                         "Hungary"                         
 [81] "Iceland"                          "India"                           
 [83] "Indonesia"                        "Iran"                            
 [85] "Iraq"                             "Ireland"                         
 [87] "Israel"                           "Italy"                           
 [89] "Jamaica"                          "Japan"                           
 [91] "Jordan"                           "Kazakhstan"                      
 [93] "Kenya"                            "Kiribati"                        
 [95] "Kuwait"                           "Kyrgyzstan"                      
 [97] "Lao PDR"                          "Latvia"                          
 [99] "Lebanon"                          "Lesotho"                         
[101] "Liberia"                          "Libya"                           
[103] "Lithuania"                        "Luxembourg"                      
[105] "Macedonia (TFYR)"                 "Madagascar"                      
[107] "Malawi"                           "Malaysia"                        
[109] "Maldives"                         "Mali"                            
[111] "Malta"                            "Marshall Islands"                
[113] "Mauritania"                       "Mauritius"                       
[115] "Mexico"                           "Micronesia (Federated States of)"
[117] "Moldova"                          "Mongolia"                        
[119] "Montenegro"                       "Morocco"                         
[121] "Mozambique"                       "Myanmar"                         
[123] "Namibia"                          "Nauru"                           
[125] "Nepal"                            "Netherlands"                     
[127] "New Zealand"                      "Nicaragua"                       
[129] "Niger"                            "Nigeria"                         
[131] "Niue"                             "North Korea"                     
[133] "Norway"                           "Occupied Palestinian Territory"  
[135] "Oman"                             "Pakistan"                        
[137] "Palau"                            "Panama"                          
[139] "Papua New Guinea"                 "Paraguay"                        
[141] "Peru"                             "Philippines"                     
[143] "Poland"                           "Portugal"                        
[145] "Puerto Rico"                      "Qatar"                           
[147] "Romania"                          "Russian Federation"              
[149] "Rwanda"                           "Saint Kitts and Nevis"           
[151] "Saint Lucia"                      "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"
[153] "Samoa"                            "Sao Tome and Principe"           
[155] "Saudi Arabia"                     "Senegal"                         
[157] "Serbia"                           "Seychelles"                      
[159] "Sierra Leone"                     "Singapore"                       
[161] "Slovakia"                         "Slovenia"                        
[163] "Solomon Islands"                  "Somalia"                         
[165] "South Africa"                     "South Korea"                     
[167] "Spain"                            "Sri Lanka"                       
[169] "Sudan"                            "Suriname"                        
[171] "Swaziland"                        "Sweden"                          
[173] "Switzerland"                      "Syrian Arab Republic"            
[175] "Taiwan"                           "Tajikistan"                      
[177] "Tanzania"                         "Thailand"                        
[179] "Timor-Leste"                      "Togo"                            
[181] "Tokelau"                          "Tonga"                           
[183] "Trinidad and Tobago"              "Tunisia"                         
[185] "Turkey"                           "Turkmenistan"                    
[187] "Tuvalu"                           "Uganda"                          
[189] "Ukraine"                          "United Arab Emirates"            
[191] "United Kingdom"                   "United States of America"        
[193] "Uruguay"                          "Uzbekistan"                      
[195] "Vanuatu"                          "Venezuela"                       
[197] "Viet Nam"                         "Yemen"                           
[199] "Zambia"                           "Zimbabwe"                        
[1] "character"
```

And this error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I am still a beginner in R. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me just fine. I rearranged the code a bit. Make sure the directory you want to write to exists, otherwise this will fail.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.by.country <- data %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  select("Country","Sex","Year.of.birth","Mean.height..cm.")  %>% 
  split(.$Country)

YourDir <- "ENTER YOUR DIR"
if(!dir.exists(YourDir)) dir.create(YourDir,recursive=T) 
lapply(names(data.by.country),function(nam)
  {
  print(nam)
  write.table(data.by.country[[nam]],paste0(YourDir, nam, ".csv"),col.names=T,sep=",")
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your code works perfectly. But I still can't figure out what was going wrong for me..

Comment: Did the directory exist?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure either then. I tried to reproduce the error and it works fine for me. Not sure what's going on there

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do your work without using for loop or excess coding

```
country <- read.csv("country_split.csv")

country_list <-split(country, as.factor(country$Country))


lapply(1:length(country_list), function(i) write.csv(country_list[[i]], 
                                                file = paste0(names(country_list[i]), ".csv"),
                                                row.names = FALSE))
```

make sure you set the working directory where you want to save the files

Comment: Thanks. Use of lapply() is efficient.